# Flutter widgets, how to use multiple async Future,. data loading questions

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a basic app, loading data into a list view widget, I have a 2nd set of data I'd like to be able to reference

This kind of thing, but in the creation of the List Tile, I want to use data from another method  called getOtherData() .. essentially to join the data but I'd rather not do it in sql/object creation..

```
                child: FutureBuilder<List<Contact>>(
                    future: getContacts(),
                    builder: (BuildContext context,
                    AsyncSnapshot<List<Contact>> snapshot) {
                    return ListView(
                          children: snapshot.hasData
                              ? snapshot.data
                                  .map((e) =>[ ListTile(
                                            leading: ExcludeSemantics(
                                                child: CircleAvatar(
                                              child: Text(e.daysSinceContacted
                                                  .toString()),
                                            )),
                                            title: Text(e.firstName),
                                            subtitle: Text(DateTime.now()
                                                    .difference(e.lastContacted)
                                                    .inDays
                                                    .toString() +
 " Days" +
 ":" +
                                                e.lastContacted
                                                    .toIso8601String() +
 getGroupName(e, groups)
                                                    .whenComplete((x) => x)),
                                            enabled: true,
                                            
                                            },
                                          ))))
                                  .toList()
                              : []);
                    })),
```

So where I do

```
title: Text(e.firstName),
```

I'd like to do

```
title: Text(e.firstName + getOtherData(e.id)
```

I can't figure out how to deal with the Future<> returns from the db sync methods though...
basically, just how do I get data so that I can use it?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way might be to use another `FutureBuilder`.

```
title: FutureBuilder<String>(
  future: getOtherData(e.id),
  builder: (_, snapshot) {
    if(!snapshot.hasData) return Container(); // or return something else while loading
    final otherData = snapshot.data;
    return Text(e.firstName + otherData);
  },
),
```